# What will be the output of the following code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, output

```
main()
{

    int a[ ] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 } ;
    int i ;
    change (a, 5 ) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\n%d", a[i] ) ;
    }
}
change ( int *b, int n )
{
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
        *( b + i ) = *( b + i ) + 5 ;
}
```

I am unable to compute the output of the above code. The problem shown while compiling the program on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php is at the definition of change() function.
The error found: error: expected expression before change(int *b, int n). I am not getting what does this mean. What expression does it demand. If b is pointer(it has address of a) then how we are making changes to its address value by adding i.

Comment: Please do not change your question with a different question when there are  answers. It makes feel that the answers are completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: Sorry Sir, i will make note of this in future.

Comment: Why you changed the original post? Now you have changed the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest functions in C. Move the definition of your `change` function outside the `main` function.

Also modern C requires you to specify a return type in your function declarations, e. g., `int main(void)`, `void change (int *b, int n)`.

**EDIT:** the question was edited and now the `change` function is no longer nested. Now OP needs a function declaration for `change` before `main` function.

Comment: Also it needs a declaration before `main`

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should not define your function in `main()`. However if you do, first define it and then use it.
Also the return type of `change` function should be `void` as this function is not returning anything and if you don't specify the return type the default is `int`.

Change `change ( int *b, int n )`  to  `void change ( int *b, int n )`.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this: here you are just adding 5 to each value of array `a`. here `a` is reference type so any changes made outside will reflect the original value that's meaning.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int  change ( int *b, int n )
  { 
            int i ;
            for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
            *( b + i ) = *( b + i ) + 5 ;
  }
  int main()
  {   

        int a[ ] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 } ;
        int i ; 
        change (a, 5 ) ; 
        for ( i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++ )
        {
            printf( "\n%d", a[i] ) ;
        }

   }
```

output :

```
7
9
11
13
15
```